# PyTorch CNN linear layer shape after conv2d

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I was trying to learn PyTorch and came across a tutorial where a CNN is defined like below,

```
class Net(Module):   
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.cnn_layers = Sequential(
            # Defining a 2D convolution layer
            Conv2d(1, 4, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            BatchNorm2d(4),
            ReLU(inplace=True),
            MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            # Defining another 2D convolution layer
            Conv2d(4, 4, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            BatchNorm2d(4),
            ReLU(inplace=True),
            MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
        )

        self.linear_layers = Sequential(
            Linear(4 * 7 * 7, 10)
        )

    # Defining the forward pass    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.cnn_layers(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.linear_layers(x)
        return x
```

I understood how the cnn_layers are made. After the cnn_layers, the data should be flattened and given to linear_layers.

I don't understand how the number of features to Linear is `4*7*7`. I understand that 4 is the output dimension from the last Conv2d layer.

How is `7*7` coming in to picture? Does stride or padding got any role in that?

Input image shape is [1, 28, 28]

Comment: what is the shape of input image?

Comment: 28x28 single channel

Comment: as far I understand the number of neurons in the Fully connected layer doesn't need to be the same as the output of Convolution layers. if you have 30 neurons in first FC layer and the out put of the conv layer is 4*7*7  you can still have 30,10 10 is the output dimension, 30 is the hidden layer dimension, there can be any number of inputs.

Comment: @cerofrais nope, that's not how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Conv2d` layers have a kernel size of 3, stride and padding of 1, which means it doesn't change the spatial size of an image. There are two `MaxPool2d` layers which reduce the spatial dimensions from `(H, W)` to `(H/2, W/2)`. So, for each batch, output of the last convolution with 4 output channels has a shape of `(batch_size, 4, H/4, W/4)`. In the forward pass feature tensor is flattened by `x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)` which makes it in the shape `(batch_size, H*W/4)`. I assume H and W are 28, for which the linear layer would take inputs of shape `(batch_size, 196)`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,
in the 2D convolution layers features [values] in a matric [2D-tensor],
As usual neural network end up with a fully connected layer followed by the logist later.
so, features in the fully-connected layer in the vector [1D-tensor].
therefore we have to map each feature [value] in the last metric into the fully-connected layer follows.
in pytorch implementation of the fully-connected layer is `Linear` class.
the first parameter is the number of input features:
in this case

```
input_image : (28,28,1)
after_Conv2d_1 : (28,28,4) <- because of the padding : if padding := 0 then (26,26,1)
after_maxPool_1 : (14,14,4) <- due to the stride of 2
after_Conv2D_2 : (14,14,4) <- because this is "same" padding
after_maxPool_2 : (7,7,4)
```

in the end, the total number of features before the fully connected layer is `4*7*7`.
Also, here shows why we use an odd number for the kernel size and start from images with even number of pixels